# Skype Web SDK throwing a few 401 errors

Tags: oauth-2.0, office365, azure-active-directory, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I have Skype for Business Online account and trying to configure skype into my web application using Skype for Web SDK.

I followed this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/developwebsdkappsforsfbonline)

I am able to authenticate user and get access token from Azure AD. Get user presence and other details. But cannot initiate audio or video calls due to the following errors.

[image]

It must be due to some missing configuration. Can any one help me resolving it ?

Comment: Did your user account has the correct rights? Means can you perform the same with an Skype client?

Comment: Yes, i can login to skype for business client with same credentials. I am able to get Access token from AD but afterwards it is giving these errors.. I am not sure what these servers are.. webpool, webdir1e, webdirgb1 etc... These calls are being made by Skype SDK automatically.